# Changing core parts of Joomla the structured way

Tags: joomla-4.x, extensions, debug

I did change various **internal parts of Joomla 4.x** to provide newbie developers more details what happened during the processing of a request. For Example:

- Added details of argument into the debug backtrace script
- Added details of the current controller, view or template, when it was or was not found
- Added details of the classes loaded be the DI component

Did that by using `Log::add()` with a new category.

During the last update, I lost my changes ;-) Therefore:

> - Does a structured way to keep such changes exist?
> - May I for example at a certain comment like SKIPUPDATE to keep this file unchanged?
> - Does the core provide well defined entry point for such stuff?

Actually, I wonder if these changes are worth being contributed to the Joomla distribution. Since the mentioned details provide invaluable details instead of more or less useless error message like 'Form not found'.

After some time, the interpretation of error messages gets simple. But up to that point, the experience isn't quite nice.

Comment: I think it could indeed be useful to have that in the Joomla core and then should be configurable with/like the debug mode. In case of an error with a form, the normal behavior should be "'Form not found'". And with the debug mode ON, it could display more info